# Rails redirect without history

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a page in our Rails application whereby when the user submits a form we want to redirect them somewhere else and if they were to click the back button in the browser, it would NOT take them back to that previous page.

Using `redirect_to our_new_path` therefore doesn't work in this case.

Our solution was to use JavaScript to handle it. So we submit the form using AJAX and then Rails responds like so:

`render json: { redirect: our_new_path }`

and then we do a replace with the response so it doesn't create the history:

`(data) => window.location.replace(data.redirect)`

However we don't really like the reliance on JavaScript for this... is it possible to do a redirect with HTTP redirects in Rails that don't create a history?